# Change jQuery UI slider size

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I am using [this UI Slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#entry-examples) and the size is the some on my site too (not the width but the button's size - demo the bottom of the page).- But [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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) the slider button's size is much nicer, smaller - demo right hand side.

So how can I change the UI Slider button's size? OR How can I add other kind of button e.g. image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

css from example page:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {

    cursor: default;
    height: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1.2em;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For who is using `vertical slider` my problem solved by the following:

```
.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
}
```