# Where can I find all the CSS properties of jQuery elements?

Tags: jquery

I am working with the jQuery slider: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Often times, I see snippets of code of people tweaking the CSS for the slider, e.g. [Change jQuery UI slider size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997990/change-jquery-ui-slider-size).

However, I don't see all these listed under the API here: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/.
Where can I find a listing of all CSS properties of jQuery slider?

Comment: This can be useful: [visualjquery](http://visualjquery.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look through [jQuery's UI's source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/themes/base). It's well-documented and easy to read through.

The default styles for the slider element are conveniently located in [`jquery.ui.slider.css`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css).

If you're using a custom theme, you'll have to inspect the element with your browser's DOM inspector and find the styles yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The sliders [api page](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) details the steps you should take if custom theme-ing the slider:

"This widget requires some functional CSS, otherwise it won't work. If you build a custom theme, use the widget's specific CSS file as a starting point."

This is located [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css)